# number converted to SVGAnimatedLenght

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a very basic Object Oriented structure for creating D3 charts. Here is the [code](http://codepen.io/akshay03/pen/VKWowy).

Without classes and function, the same code worked fine and built the chart. However, when I organize it in the above way, the values `this.width` and `this.height` get converted into `SVGAnimatedLength`, so I am unable to perform normal operations on them(such as `this.height - yScale(x)`).

I noticed that, `this.width` and `this.height` remain numbers just before the code which adds columns is encountered.

```
this.chart.selectAll(".bar") ...
```

To reproduce, if you put a breakpoint and debug the above variables, they show up as numbers until the above code(line 38) is executed. Then suddenly, they turn into `SVGAnimatedLength`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` has changed within the function.

so instead of doing in line 38:

```
 this.chart.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(this.data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.letter); })
            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.frequency); })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return this.height - yScale(d.frequency);//value of this is diffrent.
            });
```

Do like this:

```
var me = this;//store the value of this in me.
        this.chart.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(this.data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.letter); })
            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.frequency); })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return me.height - yScale(d.frequency);//use me variable
            });
    } 
}
```

working code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwxppO?editors=0010#0)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.